# Directory to string, Java

Tags: java, directory

I'm new to java, I got the path from the user, using `chooser.getCurrentDirectory()`, now i want to use the directory to create a file there, `File report = new File(chooser directory + "filename")`, but it only accepts string, not file, so how can i get the chooser directory as a string?

Comment: Please post your code that you have so far.

Comment: try { String choosertitle = null;

 pathchooser = new JFileChooser(); 
pathchooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
                           pathchooser.showSaveDialog(null);                     
    File report = new File(pathchooser.getCurrentDirectory()+filename+" calibration report");

Answer (score 4):

You should not use `chooser.getCurrentDirectory()` to start off with, you should use `chooser.getSelectedFile();`.

And you should take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html, specifically at the `get*()` methods that involve the filename.

Comment: @user2017463 Could you mark the answer as accepted if you think this is the correct answer? For more reference look at: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Actually, there is a problem, now when i choose a directory like (C:\Users\me\Documents), to save the file (example.txt) it saves the file to (C:\Users\me) with the name (Documentsexample.txt)

Comment: You'd need to show the exact code for that, you could for example post it in a new question, I'll get back to it then.

Comment: 'pathchooser = new JFileChooser();
 pathchooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
pathchooser.showSaveDialog(null);
 File report = new File(pathchooser.getSelectedFile()+filename+"calibration report");'

This is the code i'm using

Comment: Add a `File.seperator` wherever you want to have a `/`.